# Windows 7/8 Strongswan IKEv2 Wrong Gateway

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ipsec, windows-8, strongswan

I have setup Strongswan on Ubuntu 14.04 from the official package. I use IKEv2 with PKI authentication and a custom authorization plugin. This works great for Android and Ubuntu clients using strongswan but not when using the Native Windows 7/8 IKEv2 client.(Machine certificates authentication). I connect to the VPN server just fine, but on the Status tab for the vpn interface it shows this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHJEh.png]

and as you can guess I can't access anything as I have broken routing.

I have censored the IP details, Client IPv4 is correctly an IP assigned from the strongswan pool at the VPN subnet. (it's no-NAT, all addresses are public routable except the origin address which is behind my home NAT router)

Comment: Are you worrying about the "Server IPv4 address 0.0.0.0" line? Or those red marked IP addresses?

Comment: the 0.0.0.0 address :P

Comment: That 0.0.0.0 address is always like that for IKEv2 connections. But the red marked IP addresses actually look like they are from the same subnet, which might be an issue.

Comment: Android clients with strongswan app and linux clients using strongswan can connect and have correct routing behavior.

Comment: As far as I could determine the censored addresses, they are from the same subnet. It might throw the Windows client off that the VPN gateway's public address and the client's **internal** tunnel IP are in the same subnet. Do you use [split tunneling](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling)? Have you disabled the _"Use default gateway on remote network"_ option in the _"Advanced TCP/IP"_ settings of the VPN connection?

Comment: Just to clarify, I use fake-arp so the client gets a public routable IPv4, no NAT takes place.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

You should specify 0.0.0.0/0 for rightsubnet for windows config, the Windows IPsec client isn't "smart enough" to handle split tunneling.

Comment: That's incorrect. You can split tunnel with the windows client. In fact, I'm doing it right now.

Comment: Really? What I have always resolved to do for all our remote windows workers is not "use gateway on remote network" and just insert the needed routes via the "route" command from a command prompt.

Comment: Yes. That's split tunneling. The Windows IKEv2 client doesn't take route pushdown (something the mac client does handle), but it'll split tunnel. Adding routing works better with the powershell command `Add-VpnConnectionRoute` and `Add-VpnConnectionTriggerTrustedNetwork` for on-demand DNS dialing.